# "set" command not working properly while running batch file through NppExec plugin of Notepad++

Tags: windows, batch-file, notepad++, nppexec

Consider this batch file :
`@echo off 
    set /p var1=Input your first name and press Enter key :
    set /p var2=Input your last name and press Enter key :
    pause`
If I run this batch file by double clicking on it, *it works fine*.
But if it is run through *console window of NppExec plugin* of Notepad++, it only waits for first input. 
 Probably, "enter" key pressed by user is taken as input for second "set" command.
One solution may be to insert one more "set" command before second "set" as:

`@echo off 
     set /p var1=Input your first name and press Enter key : 
     set /p temp=
     set /p var2=Input your last name and press Enter key :
     pause` 
But then problem will arise, when this batch file wiil be run through command prompt or simply by double clicking on it (will wait for three inputs).
Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried it without the indent.

Comment: How do you run this batch file? Maybe you need to wrap it to real `cmd`-command: `cmd /c yourbatchfile.cmd`.

Comment: @user694733 I run this batch file as : **In console of NppExec, go to batch file directory and type    batchfile.cmd**   I tried cmd /c batchfile.cmd, I also used cmd /c before "set" command(s) in my batch file. Nothing worked.

Comment: @09stephenb Yes, actually I tried without indent.

Answer (score 1):

See if this changes the behaviour by adding a delay

```
@echo off 
set /p "var1=Input your first name and press Enter key: "
for /L %%a in (1,1,500000) do rem
set /p "var2=Input your last name and press Enter key: "
pause
```

Comment: No, Still not waiting for second input. Here is the result of console window of NppExec :
_Input your first name and press Enter key: FirstInput
Input your last name and press Enter key: Press any key to continue . . ._